# bullying and harassment are rife in academia

Tags: word-usage

> The complaints that launched the investigations allege that the pair — Sofia Feltzing and Melvyn Davies — bullied colleagues using their positions of power, and that Lund University officials failed to act strongly enough following multiple reports over the years. Although **bullying and harassment are rife in academia**, this case is unusual because it pits many members of an academic division against two of its most senior professors, alleging long-lasting and widespread harm.

Source: [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01621-8)

Does "bullying and harassment are **rife** in academia" mean "bullying and harassment are **very common** in academia"? It seems to me that "rife" sounds more euphemistic than "very common". I am not sure whether I am on the right track.

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/rife?locale=en

Comment: I find it amusing that you think ***"rife" sounds more euphemistic***. As a Brit, I think pestilential dogs are ***rife** with fleas*, whereas promising new territories might be ***ripe** with opportunity*. Apparently, plenty of people (primarily Americans?) have no problem with ***rife*** in that ***positive*** second context. To me (as a Brit?), the associations of ***ripe*** are often/usually good, but ***rife*** is always bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "rife" directly means "very common", "frequent" or "widespread". However, "rife" is not being used as an euphemism in this passage, it's more colorful and literary, in the sense that "bullying and harassment" are "all over the place" in academia. The term emphasizes the contentious nature of academia.

Comment: I just voted, thanks for bringing it to my attention.